# multiplying Persistenance of an integer

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a code that does the following:

Multiplying the digits of an integer and continuing the process gives the surprising result that the sequence of products always arrives at a single-digit number.

For example:

715 -> 35 -> 15 -> 5

88 -> 64 -> 24 -> 8

27 -> 14 -> 4
The number of products necessary to reach the single-digit number is called the persistence number of that integer. Thus 715 and 88 have a persistence number of 3, while 27 has persistence 2. Make a program to find the only two-digit number with persistence greater than 3?

I was able to come up with a rough idea and the code is below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int PersistentNum(int digit)
{
    int x;
    int pers = 0;
    int y = 1;

    while(x > 9)
    {
        do {
            x = digit % 10;
            y = y * digit;
            x = x / 10;
        } while(x > 0);
        pers++;
        x = y;
    }
    return pers;
}

int main()
{
    int repNum;
    int Persist;
    cout << "Please enter a  non-zero, positive integer: ";
    cin >> repNum;

    Persist = PersistentNum(repNum);

    cout << " the Persistence of " << repNum <<" is " << Persist;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "_doesn't seem to work_".

Comment: You want the code for finding a two digit number with persistence greater than 3 right?But the largest two digit number is 99 and according to your definition its persistence 99->81->8 is 2 .So no use of writing code

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala Try it with 88.

Comment: @Rags he asked persistence greater than 3 but the persistence of 88 is 3

Comment: Try with 77.....

Comment: Also, `while(x > 9)`...`x` is uninitialized first time through.

Comment: i want the number that is inputed for example 715 should go down to 35 then to 15 then to 5 , so it shows the persistence is 3.

Comment: Also, consider using variable names that are more descriptive than just `x` and `y`. Here's an example of your code with different names. I think it is easier to follow/debug. https://ideone.com/MiNTNP

Comment: @JE3 you can take a glance at my code

Comment: @JE3 i have used break i my code because 77 is the only two digit number with persistence >3

Comment: 77 is the only two digit number with persistence >3

Comment: I recommend inputting the number as text (string).  You can then access the digits as:  `int numeric_digit = number_as_text[i] - '0';`

Comment: learn to use your debugger

Comment: @GaneshChowdarySadanala Indeed. My point was merely that starting with higher numbers didn't automatically produce a higher persistence,  which seemed to be what you were suggesting apologies if I misunderstood what you were saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to assign **y** every time as it here retains the old already multiplied value.

also you messed up the meaning of x and digit in your original code

instead of

```
func(int x)
```

you wrote

```
func(int digit)
```

corrected code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int PersistentNum(int x)
{
    int digit;
    int pers = 0;
    int y =1 ;

    while(x > 9)
    {
        y = 1;

        do{
           digit = x % 10;
           y = y* digit;
           x = x/10;
        }while(x > 0);

        pers++;
        x = y;
    }
    return pers;
}

int main()
{
    int repNum;
    int Persist;


    cout<<"Please enter a  non-zero, positive integer: ";
    cin>>repNum;

    Persist = PersistentNum(repNum);

    cout<< " the Persistence of " << repNum <<" is " << Persist;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so i assigned y but now it is outputing 1  no matter what the input is:       

        while(digit> 9)
        {
        y = 1;
        do{ 
        x = digit % 10;
        y = digit * y;
        x = x/10;
        
        }while(x> 0);
        
        pers++;
        x=y;
        
        return pers;
        }
        }

Answer (score 0):

As per your question ,You want me we to find for 2 digit number

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{int y;int z;int temp;int n;
 for(int x=10;x<100;x++)
 {temp=0;n=x;
  while(x>9){
  y=x%10;
  z=x/10;
  x=y*z;temp++;
  }
  x=n;
   if(temp>3){
   cout<<"number is "<<n<<"persistence is"<<temp;
 /*number is 77 persistence is 4 */
   break;}/*i have used break i my code because 77 is the only two digit number with persistence >3*/
  }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to initialize x before the first loop- or just using `do..while` loop in both of the loops, read about garbage values.

```
int PersistentNum(int number)
{
    int digit, pers = 0, curr_num;

    do {
        curr_num = 1;

        do {
            digit = number % 10;
            curr_num = curr_num * digit;
            number = number / 10;
        } while(number > 0);

        cout << curr_num << " ";
        number = curr_num;
        pers++;

    } while(number > 9);

    cout << endl;
    return pers;
}
```